# Select 'Please Select' if var does not match value in dropdown

Tags: symfony, twig

I am new to Twig and struggling with the following scenario.

I have a `select` for country names (United Kingdom & Republic of Ireland) and I'm struggling when the Twig variable value returned does not match a value in the `select`.

I have it working if the variable is empty but need help with the above.

This is my full `select` HTML (I have removed all the Twig code to make it clear)

```
<select id="compAddCountryDd" name="compAddCountryDd" class="form-control address">
    <option value='' class="optionPlaceholder">Please Select</option>
    <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="Republic of Ireland">Republic of Ireland</option>
</select>
```

[image]

This is the code I have for my 'Please Select' `option` if empty, which I have working

```
{% if companyDetails is defined and companyDetails.address.country == '' %}
    <option value='' class="optionPlaceholder"
            selected style="display: none" disabled>
        Please Select
    </option>
{% endif %}
```

But I can't seem to get it to display if the variable is `defined` but does not match the values in the `select`.

This I have tried the following code for the Twig `if`

```
{% if companyDetails is defined and companyDetails.address.country == '' and
      companyDetails.address.country != 'United Kingdom' and
      companyDetails.address.country != 'Republic of Ireland' %}
```

and also

```
{% if companyDetails is defined and companyDetails.address.country == '' or
      companyDetails.address.country != 'United Kingdom' or
      companyDetails.address.country != 'Republic of Ireland' %}
```

Basically, I need my 'Please Select' `option` to be displayed if it:

1. Is defined
2. Does not equal 'United Kingdom'
3. Does not equal 'Republic of Ireland'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some parentheses here to comply to your logic:

- You want to the variable to be defined
- AND
- The country is either empty OR not equal to the UK AND not equal to Ireland

```
{% if companyDetails|default and (companyDetails.address.country|trim == '' or companyDetails.address.country != 'United Kingdom' and companyDetails.address.country != 'Republic of Ireland') %}
    Show
{% else %}
    Don't show
{% endif %}
```

I would however rewrite this to the following:

```
{% if companyDetails|default and (companyDetails.address.country|trim == '' or companyDetails.address.country not in [ 'United Kingdom', 'Republic of Ireland' ]) %}
    Show
{% else %}
    Don't show
{% endif %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/t56zto)

Answer (score 0):

It will be a good opportunity to create a form class with a ChoiceType ?
Easier to manage in your controller (get repository, show/not show/disabled), to separate code and to add translations

Some good examples in the doc : https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html

Another one good example : https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-forms/dynamic-choice-type